# Proxy using selenium 4.13 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm encountering the following error :
TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'

Actually my code is:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

    proxy_setting = Proxy({
      'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
      'httpProxy': f"{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}",
      'noProxy': ''
    })
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy_setting)
```

Can anyone help me?